# UAC-account-users can't see their mounted network-drives

Tags: uac, mapping

I wrote a few login batches in the Group Policy Management which mount specified devices to specified usergroups. The batches work as they should as long UAC is disabled.

My problem is that the UAC-account-users can't see their mounted network-drives because the login scripts run in elevated context. I tried to fix the problem with PsExec (-l) so that the network-folders are mapped with limited user rigths. But it seems that this won't work. (PsExec is already installed on all computers so it can work local.)

Has anyone an idea how to fix that problem? I spended a long time in trying to fix the problem but I did not find any solutions about THIS problem.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault. If the answer is right and solves your problem, please accept the answer (and if the answer is good, give it an upvote too). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See if this Microsoft TechNet article helps:

[After you turn on User Account Control in Windows Vista, programs may be unable to access some network locations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624)

> This problem occurs because User Account Control treats members of the Administrators group as standard users. Therefore, network shares that are mapped by logon scripts are shared with the standard user access token instead of with the full administrator access token. 
>   [...]